# Unable to manupulate the list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am having below class:

```
 public class statistics
    {
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool Flag { get; set; }
    }
```

Above is list of statistics class so it contains records like this:

```
1st record : Type = 1
             Title = "abc,ttt"
             flag= true

2nd Records : Type = 1
             Title = "xyz"
             flag= true

3rd Records : Type = 1
              Title = "lmn,ggg"
              flag= true
```

So here I would like to manipulate my statistics variable and so my 
statistics variable should contains **5 records** like below:

```
1st record : Type = 1
             Title = "abc"
             flag= true


2nd record : Type = 1
             Title = "ttt"
             flag= true

3rd Records : Type = 
             Title = "xyz"
             flag= true

4th Records : Type = 1
              Title = "lmn"
              flag= true

5th Records : Type = 1
              Title = "ggg"
              flag= true
```

So as you can see that I would like to have a separate record if title contains comma-separated records.

```
For eg:1st record : Type = 1
             Title = "abc,ttt"
             flag= true
```

abc and ttt should split into two records as title contains comma-separated records.

This is how I am trying but unable to do it:

```
statistics = statistics.Select(o => o.Title.Split(',')).
                            Select(
                                        t => new statistics
                                        {
                                            Type = t.   // not working
                                        }
                                        ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for `Split` (to turn single *comma separated* `Type` into several items) and `SelectMany` (to *flatten* the collection):

```
List<statistics> source = .....;

var result = source
  .SelectMany(item => item.Title //split title 
     .Split(',')
     .Select(title => new statistics() {
        Type = item.Type,
        Title = title,
        Flag = item.Flag }))
  .ToList(); // finally, materialize into list
```

Comment: Shouldn't `item => item.Type` be `item => item.Title`?

Comment: @Guy: thank you! it should be `item => item.Title` for sure.

Comment: Yes this worked.thank you so much for the kind help and please keep helping :)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
var result = statistics.Select(s => s.Title.Split(',')
    .Select(x => new statistics {Type = s.Type, Flag = s.Flag, Title = x}))
    .SelectMany(s=>s)
    .ToList();
```

With this output:

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = statistics.SelectMany(s => s.Title.Split(new char[] { ',' }).
Select(t => new statistics() { Title = t, Flag = s.Flag, Type = s.Type }));
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should always contain an explanation.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

A bit nicer with the query syntax, but don't use the same name `statistics` for both the class and list:

```
var result = (from s in statistics
              from a in s.Title.Split(',')
              select new statistics(){ Type = s.Type, Title = a, Flag = s.Flag }).ToList();
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this :)